# SSL websites with http external links

Tags: javascript, html, ssl

I have a problem on my SSL website. I tried to add an external JavaScript link to my website. The JavaScript link is http and my website which is https, locks the script link for be http. This is the code of the script in http:

```html
    <div class="container radio">
    <p>Próximo evento: 29/04/16</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.wavestreamer.com/cgi-bin/swf.js?id=1SCZICL137KEA3GK"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.wavestreaming.com/?id=1SCZICL137KEA3GK"></script>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way my site https display the content?

The link of my site is this: https://www.insidecraft.com/radio.html

My second website whose haven´t got SSL works perfectly with is exactly the same code: http://us.insidecraft.com/pruebas2/radio.html

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Why you not just download the scripts from http://player.wavestreamer.com/cgi-bin/swf.js?id=1SCZICL137KEA3GK and  http://player.wavestreaming.com/?id=1SCZICL137KEA3GK and to place there of *your* web site? Moreover you should fix `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js` to `https` too. I strictly recommend you to disable SSL3, TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA on your site.

Comment: I'd recommend you to follow settings suggested by [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.2.22&openssl=1.0.1e&hsts=yes&profile=intermediate). I recommend you to test your site by free Qualys SSL test: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.insidecraft.com&s=164.132.159.220 before the changes and after there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because browsers block active mixed content. You could configure the browser to allow it (at least in firefox). But this only works if you could change the configuration of all browser visiting your site (e.g corporate-network). Only other option is serving the script over HTTPS aswell. As workaround you could also put it in an `<script>` tag inside the document, served securly. Or copy the script to your HTTPS doamin. [MDN on mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

---

If you load the page with your browsers development console opened, it should show an error saying that mixed active content has been blocked.